# How to check my redux storage is encrypted or not - React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, encryption, redux

I have been using [redux-persist-transform-encrypt](https://github.com/maxdeviant/redux-persist-transform-encrypt#readme) package to encrypt my redux storage data inside the app.

What I want to know is how to check whether my redux data is encrypted or not?

Answer (score 1):

You can check it from Local Storage section in Chrome DevTools. As you can see below my redux data is encrypted by redux-persist-transform-encrypt

[image: Local Storage]